# How to reattach electrical clevis to brick garage

Tags: electrical, garage

My garage has a 30A aerial service line from the main house. A cable provides strain relief support. This support cable is attached by ceramic clevis at each end. The clevis at the garage end has pulled away from the bricks. How should I go about reattaching this?

The clevis was previously attached with 1.5" screws into blue concrete anchors. I am thinking 3" Tapcons would be more secure, or is there a better way?

Once I re-mount the clevis, how do I tension the cable to reattach it? It's a ~20' run, so reasonably heavy/awkward to try and pull it manually. I guess I could rig up some kind of temporary pulley or ratchet setup, but this doesn't seem all that robust and I wonder if there's a proper tool or trick?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to check with your local electric utility before you touch this.  In many places everything from the meter to the pole is considered to be their responsibility.

Comment: Are those two holes in the brick where this was attached?  If so I'm puzzled about how it "pulled away" when the force is almost perfectly perpendicular and there is no sign of damage to the brick.  What force caused it to pull straight out of the wall?  I would want to know this before solving the problem.

Comment: This is a private line, from my house to my garage, so definitely owned by me. I think it pulled out because the wire passes through a grape vine and a tree. They likely pushed on things on a windy day. I've cut them back now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question wrote "aerial service line from the main house" which suggests that this is a privately-owned cable -- it isn't the power utility's service drop, and therefore it is the home owner's responsibility to fix this. Better to do it soon before the strain causes damage to the electrical conductors!

Arrange a temporary loop of some kind around the clamp on the messenger wire (the support cable). This could be made from a bit of wire, paracord, etc.

Feed some cord through the gap behind the clevis mounting plate. Paracord might be a good choice. Tie it off with a knot such as a bowline.

Feed the standing end of the cord through the temporary loop and then through the loop at the clevis bracket. This arrangement gives 2:1 mechanical advantage -- the advantage is the same as if the cord went through the temporary loop only, but the addition of going through the bowline loop too sets things up so that your pulling force pulls you and the ladder toward the wall, rather than away from the wall and toward certain doom (ie falling off the ladder).

Pull the standing end of the cord. When the loop of the messenger wire clamp is drawn into the clevis sufficiently, use one hand to pinch the paracord lead against itself where it passes through the bowline loop. That'll (mostly) prevent it slackening while you use the other hand to tie off the paracord. Finally, the messenger wire will be held taut by the paracord so that you'll have both hands free to assemble the clevis.

[image: sketch of cord for pulling]

Comment: This looks good. Thanks for the diagram. Do you think 3" Tapcons would be appropriate here?

Comment: @Roberto Those might be sufficient, but I'd consider expansion anchors for maximum strength.  Assuming you can find them small enough for the holes in that thing.

Comment: @Roberto My experience with anchoring things to brick is pretty limited. But I'll mention that bricks often have hollow voids inside them. The portion of a 3" Tapcon that goes into a void, or even just near a void, won't be contributing to the strength of the connection. I'd estimate that you have 1.5" of useful embedment to work with and suggest to choose the fastener style, diameter, and length accordingly.

Comment: I didn't quite get the job done, but am accepting this answer anyways because the idea was sound and I got so close. Ultimately I got things to about an inch away before calling it. I decided it's time to call a pro before I hurt myself! (That said, the clevis mount is now anchored very securely with 2" sleeve bolts. So that part was a win, at least.)